# Working using swift and logInWithPublishPermissions

Tags: swift2

I have this code:

```
let login: FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()  
    login.logInWithPublishPermissions(["publish_actions"], handler: { (result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) -> Void in  
        if error != nil {  
            NSLog(error.localizedFailureReason!)  
        } else if result.isCancelled {  
            NSLog("Canceled")  
        } else if result.grantedPermissions.contains("publish_actions") {  
            self.loginFacebookButtin.hidden = true  
        }  
    })
```

This code worked ok, but I have this warning message:

'logInWithPublishPermissions(_:handler:)' is deprecated: use logInWithPublishPermissions:fromViewController:handler: instead

I tried to fix this warning but I could not. Someone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [FBSDK API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKLoginManager/):

The way you're using the method is deprecated. It wants you to use the new way it indicated in its documentation, as seen below:

```
- (void)
logInWithPublishPermissions:    (NSArray *)permissions
                    handler:    (FBSDKLoginManagerRequestTokenHandler)handler
__attribute__((deprecated("use logInWithPublishPermissions:     fromViewController:handler: instead")));
```

Therefore you would use it like so:

```
let login: FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()  
login.logInWithPublishPermissions(["publish_actions"], fromViewController: self, handler: { (response: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) in  
    if (error != nil) {  
        NSLog(error.localizedFailureReason!)  
    } else if result.isCancelled {  
        NSLog("Canceled")  
    } else if result.grantedPermissions.contains("publish_actions") {  
        self.loginFacebookButtin.hidden = true  
    }  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function like this:

```
let login: FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()  
login.logInWithPublishPermissions(["publish_actions"], fromViewController: self, handler: { (result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) -> Void in  
    if error != nil {  
        NSLog(error.localizedFailureReason!)  
    } else if result.isCancelled {  
        NSLog("Canceled")  
    } else if result.grantedPermissions.contains("publish_actions") {  
        self.loginFacebookButtin.hidden = true  
    }  
})
```

Comment: Please explain, why the function should be called like this.

Comment: The method is deprecated so according to the documentation you must call the method like "logInWithPublishPermissions:fromViewController:handler:"

Comment: Ok. Please add this to your answer instead of posting a comment. You will find an **edit** link below your answer. And please read the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).